# How to automatically create rows and pass values to other tables

Tags: sql-server, database

[image]

There are three tables in database:

1. "BusinessEntity " which has the identity column "BusinessEntityID" as Primary Key (as well as rowguid and ModifiedDate columns).
2. "Firm" which has similarly the identity column "BusinessEntityID" as Primary Key, which is also a Foreign Key to BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID (it has a 1-to-1 relationship with "BusinessEntity" table, FirmName, rowguid and ModifiedDate columns ).
3. "Customer" which has the identity column "CustomerID" as Primary Key and column "FirmID" as Foreign Key to Firm .BusinessEntityID (plus CustomerName, rowguid and ModifiedDate columns).

i.e. (also see image)

```
tables:  BusinessEntity            Firm                          Customer
columns:                                                         CustomerID (PK)
         BusinessEntityID(PK) -->  BusinessEntityID (PK/FK) -->  FirmID (FK)
```

What I'm trying to do is whenever a new Customer row is to be created:
A new BusinessEntity row to be created automatically and then pass its BusinessEntityID value to an (automatically) newly created Firm row which it turn would pass its own BusinessEntityID to Customer table as FirmID column.

As you can see a BusinessEntity row was no meaning unless it corresponds to a Firm (or other entities) and a Customer must include a Firm.

I created a view containing all three tables along with a trigger to do the job without success. Any suggestions?

The tables:

1. BusinessEntity

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo ].[BusinessEntity](
      [BusinessEntityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
      [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
   (
      [BusinessEntityID] ASC
   )
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BusinessEntity] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_BusinessEntity_rowguid]  
    DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [rowguid]
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo ].[BusinessEntity] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_BusinessEntity_ModifiedDate]  
     DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ModifiedDate]
   GO
   ```
2. Firm

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Firm](
   [BusinessEntityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [FirmName] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
   [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
   [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Firm_BusinessEntityID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
      (
      [BusinessEntityID] ASC
      )
      ) ON [PRIMARY]
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Firm] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Firm_rowguid]  
     DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [rowguid]
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Firm] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Firm_ModifiedDate]  
     DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ModifiedDate]
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Firm]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Firm_BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityID] FOREIGN KEY([BusinessEntityID])
     REFERENCES [dbo].[BusinessEntity] ([BusinessEntityID])
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Firm] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Firm_BusinessEntity_BusinessEntityID]
   GO
   ```
3. Customer

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
   [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [FirmID] [int] NULL,
   [CustomerName] [nvarchar](28) NULL,
   [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
   [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, 

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer_CustomerID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
     (
     [CustomerID] ASC
     )
     ) ON [PRIMARY]
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_rowguid]                  
      DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [rowguid]
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_ModifiedDate]  
      DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ModifiedDate]
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Customer_Firm_FirmID] FOREIGN KEY([FirmID])
      REFERENCES [dbo].[Firm] ([BusinessEntityID])
   GO

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Customer_Firm_FirmID]
   GO
   ```

Something weird happens here. I created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateFirmCustomer](@FirmName NVARCHAR(30), @CustomerName NVARCHAR(28)) AS 
BEGIN;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT BusinessEntity DEFAULT VALUES;
DECLARE @BusinessEntityID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Firm] ON

INSERT Firm(BusinessEntityID, FirmName)
VALUES (@BusinessEntityID, @FirmName);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Firm] OFF

INSERT Customer(FirmID, CustomerName)
VALUES (@BusinessEntityID, @CustomerName);
DECLARE @CustomerID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

SELECT @BusinessEntityID AS FirmID, @CustomerID AS CustomerID;

COMMIT;
END;

GO
```

When I run it sometimes the CustomerID column gets the value of BusinessEntityID column when it should really be independently auto-generated. Also the BusinessEntityID column auto-generates weird values e.g. jumped from value 7 to value 1002. (BusinessEntityID is BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID ) Any clues? (see picture)

[image]

Now I created this view to insert Customers as Firms:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vBusEntityFirmCustomer]
AS
SELECT dbo.Firm.FirmName, dbo.Customer.CustomerName
FROM dbo.BusinessEntity INNER JOIN
     dbo.Firm ON dbo.BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID = dbo.Firm.BusinessEntityID INNER JOIN
     dbo.Customer ON dbo.Firm.BusinessEntityID = dbo.Customer.FirmID
GO
```

And this trigger on the view:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_FirmCustomer]
ON [dbo].[vBusEntityFirmCustomer]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
   exec [dbo].[CreateFirmCustomer]
GO
```

But every time I enter a new FirmName CustomerName to insert a new row I get this message (see image):

Procedure or function 'CreateFirmCustomer' expects parameter '@FirmName', which was not supplied.
The fact is that I do supply FirmName.

[image]

Comment: A trigger on `BusinessEntity` *would* do the job. (A trigger on a view would not, unless you plan to insert rows only using the view.) What do you have so far and why isn't it working?

Comment: Any code for this trigger? You see there are three tables involved here.

Comment: Since, presumably, you can't  *guess* the required `FirmName`/ `CustomerName` from `BusinessEntity` alone, is there anything wrong with writing a stored procedure to initially create the entity/firm/customer trio through a simple sequence of statements? This sounds much more convenient than cobbling together a view. Something like `CreateBusiness(@FirmName NVARCHAR(30), @CustomerName NVARCHAR(28)`). (Incidentally, strongly consider longer `NVARCHAR`s, 28 characters sounds awfully easy to overflow if this comes from user input and is not imposed by some other database.)

Comment: Well I'm afraid my knowledge on stored procedures is somehow limited. Would you please be I bit more specific?

Comment: Well, I immediately run into trouble writing the sproc because it becomes obvious that `BusinessEntity` is meaningless. It holds only IDs, identical to those in `Firm`. If you intend to have more than one kind of `BusinessEntity` (beyond `Firm`), then at the very least there should be some kind of `Type` column. If the relationship really is 1-to-1, why have `BusinessEntity` at all? You must, at the very least, determine which of these two tables should have an autogenerated `IDENTITY` -- they cannot both have one if they are to be synchronized, or at least, one would be `FirmID` instead.

Comment: 'BusinessEntity' table holds other types beyond 'Firm' (e.g. 'Person') but it does not require a 'Type' column. The IDENTITIES' that have to be autogenerated are 'BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID' and 'CustomerID'.

Comment: Then `Firm.BusinessEntityID` should not be `IDENTITY`, since it will simply take its value from `BusinessEntity`. (Also, without a `Type`, keep in mind that it will not be possible to efficiently check what a `BusinessEntity` is -- you need to check every possible table linking to it for a particular row with that ID when you want to know.)

Comment: So Firm table (the relationship is 1-to-1 with BusinessEntity table) will not have an IDENTITY column. I just try to apply the Microsoft AdventureWorks database schema which is exactly as mine...

Comment: AdventureWorks is not intended to reflect best practices in database design. Its primary use is to serve as a guinea pig to demonstrate SQL features, which means it tends to be overcomplicated to allow a demonstration of those features. Don't treat its design decisions as gospel. In particular, if you have no demonstrable business need for a table like `BusinessEntity`, then don't have a table called `BusinessEntity`. If you are never going to use `ModifiedDate`, then don't have `ModifiedDate`. Transactional replication does not require `rowguid`. And so forth, and so on.

Comment: Identities are *not* guaranteed to be consecutive (only increasing), so yes, it *is* possible for an identity to go from 7 to (say) 1002, particularly if you restart SQL Server (rolling back a transaction will also not reset the identity and leave  a gap). If you need consecutive values with no gaps, you want to look at sequences. The `Customer` identity *is* independently generated, but of course, if you generate firms and customers at the same rate, they can be expected to track each other closely. Two values that are independent can still be the same -- they're just not *always* the same.

Comment: Now I get this error message "Procedure or function 'CreateFirmCustomer' expects parameter '@FirmName', which was not supplied."...

Comment: Your question has now turned into an extended support session... this is going beyond what a SO question should be doing. Your last question boils down to "how do I invoke stored procedures (from a trigger)". If you're unclear on that, make a new question.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for all your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, as designed, you have to create a `BusinessEntity` first, then a `Firm`, then a `Customer`. Across all these tables, the only real *information* you're storing is the firm name and the customer name -- all the rest is derived and autogenerated by the database. We can encapsulate the operation `CreateCustomer` in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateCustomer(@FirmName NVARCHAR(30), @CustomerName NVARCHAR(28)) AS 
BEGIN;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT BusinessEntity DEFAULT VALUES;
    DECLARE @BusinessEntityID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT Firm(BusinessEntityID, FirmName)
    VALUES (@BusinessEntityID, @FirmName);

    INSERT Customer(FirmID, CustomerName)
    VALUES (@BusinessEntityID, @CustomerName);
    DECLARE @CustomerID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    -- Return IDs of the newly created rows as the result set
    SELECT @BusinessEntityID AS FirmID, @CustomerID AS CustomerID;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Invoke as (for example) `EXEC CreateCustomer 'Firm', 'Customer'`. With the table definitions as given, this will fail because `Firm.BusinessEntityID` is an `IDENTITY` -- if it is to take its value from `BusinessEntity`, it shouldn't be. (You can work around this with `IDENTITY_INSERT`, but in a properly designed database this shouldn't be necessary.)

Another thing that's obviously weird is that we insert *no* business data at all in `BusinessEntity` (which is why we need the `DEFAULT VALUES` syntax) -- it's nothing but a super-general container of IDs, so it's of dubious value. Nevertheless, this demonstrates the general technique of inserting rows in multiple tables that have dependencies.

As written, this stored procedure always creates a new `Firm` and `BusinessEntity` to go along with the `Customer`. Logically, a `Firm` can have more than one `Customer`, so you probably want another stored procedure to create a `Customer` for an existing `Firm`. This is simpler, as it's just an `INSERT` in `Customer` with the appropriate `FirmID`. You may wish to have a separate `CreateFirm` stored procedure that you call first, followed by a `CreateCustomer` to add a customer for that firm.

Comment: Jeroen it worked just fine. Only had to add SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Firm] ON and then OFF. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: There is nothing to be gained from keeping the ID in `Firm` `IDENTITY`. It is impossible to insert a row into it using the identity value, because a corresponding row must already exist in `BusinessEntity` (and therefore the ID is relady determined). The only possible reason one would have `IDENTITY` there is backwards compatibility with an existing table that cannot be changed. If that's the case in your design, that's fine, but a new schema should simply leave out the `IDENTITY` there.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. How could I combine this stored procedure with a view of the tables of the procedure that would allow for CRUD actions?

Comment: @galaf: with a view, `INSTEAD OF` triggers on that view, and considerable difficulty. For example, if you insert a row for a firm/company that does not yet exist, both should be created, but if you insert one for an existing firm and a new company, only the company should be created. When a row is deleted, similarly difficult calls have to be made. This is not typically the sort of task you give to a database; instead, the application usually breaks up such operations as appropriate.  If you really want to go down that road, try it and ask new questions when you're stuck.

Comment: Jeroen, there is some kind of weird behaviour when running the procedure. Please have a look at the end of question. A Firm doesn't have Customers. It's the other way round: A Customer can be a Firm or Person. So in fact the Customer table includes a PersonID column that is FK to Person table.

Answer (score 0):

According to me,

it all depend how and when those 3 tables are populated.
Suppose those three table are populated using single UI, then

I will write them in **single proc within one transaction**.

Suppose those 3 table will be will populated at diff stage i.e diff UI then i write them in diff proc as you have already define constraint.

BTW what is the purpose of rowguid in all 3 tables.

Comment: They should be populated using a single UI. The rowguid is there for replication purposes.